# Name of sci-fi horror from 80s with a small eye on tentacle coming out of mans forehead

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I recall watching this film as a kid in the mid 80s and it really scared me at the time. It was to do with scientists making a machine that made monsters (that apparently exist all the time but we cannot see) become visible. There was a part where one of the main characters grows some kind of small eye on a stalk that comes out of his forehead. It was quite a gory film - at one point he tries to eat a womans brain (using her eye socket as entry point). It was so many years ago I just cannot recall the name of the film and I would quite like to see it again to see how badly it has aged. Can anyone recall this from the vague description above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely [From Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_%28film%29); an adaptation of a [HP Lovecraft story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_%28short_story%29) that involves a man creating a machine to allow us to see using an unused part of the brain, specifically, the pineal gland.

I found the movie pleasantly gory as a teen, but I enjoy the story much more; if you haven't had a chance to read it, here's a [copy](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/From_Beyond).  (It passed into public domain a few years ago.)

<strike>Here's a Youtube [clip](http://youtu.be/zgZuCXY-vR8?t=1m8s) that might confirm it for you,</strike>  -- Sadly, this clip has been removed.

I think this is the other image you remember:

[image: Eating the Eyeball -- used under Fair Use doctrine]

Comment: Yes that is the film. What a thoroughly unpleasant image.